# count TOTAL duplicates

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a table like this:

| First_Name | Last_Name |
| --- | --- |
| Elton | John |
| Lady | Gaga |
| Elton | John |
| Elton | John |
| Mariah | Carey |
| Mariah | Carey |

I want to count how many redundant entries I have. My final result should be "3" (2 extra for Elton and 1 extra for Mariah).

I have tried:

`select count(First_Name) from Names group by First_Name having count(First_Name)>1`

and

`select sum(*) from (select count(First_Name) from Names group by First_Name having count(First_Name)>1)`

but it it is off by 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select count of duplicates for every entry - 1 so you will have count of duplicated entries without original. Than sum this results.

```
select sum(count_duplicates) from (select count(First_Name) - 1 as count_duplicates from Names group by First_Name having count(First_Name)>1)
```

Look like you main problem that you sum(*) instead of count of duplicates

Answer (score 2):

You can try this Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT First_Name, Last_Name) AS Redundant_Count FROM Names;
```

This query calculates the total count of rows in your table and subtracts the count of distinct combinations of First_Name and Last_Name. The result will give you the count of redundant entries.

**COUNT(*)** *counts the total number of rows in the table*.

**COUNT(DISTINCT First_Name, Last_Name)** *counts the number of unique combinations of* **First_Name** and **Last_Name**.

Comment: this is so much more efficient than what I was trying to do, thank you for the help!